# how do i keep ubuntu & windows dual boot when updating to win 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, windows-10

I have a Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu dual boot on my hp pro-book, and when i update to Win 10, the dual boot and the second hard drive partition are inaccessible. When i downgrade back to Win 8.1 the dual boot is back and Ubuntu is accessible, how do i update my PC to Win 10 and keep the dual boot?
thanks.

Comment: Scroll down to: _Installing Windows After Ubuntu_ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu and Windows paritions are on the same drive, when you upgrade to Windows 10, I think Windows 10 overwrites GRUB.

- I think you will have to use Ubuntu's live cd and install GRUB again.
- If even after doing so you cannot see GRUB, check your BIOS settings and increase the priority of Ubuntu (GRUB) so that it is executed before Windows' bootloader

Comment: will this delete my previous Ubuntu?

Comment: @user5946707 No it will not. It will just install the bootloader.

Comment: an dhow do i install Ubuntu live on my portable hrd drive?

Comment: Refer to this article: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Ubuntu-Live-Cd

Step 6 onwards, you can use UNetbootin if you want